# How to create a computed column based on other columns of a BIRT crosstab

Tags: birt, crosstab

My report specs is summed up by the illustration below:

```
--------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
        |         January      |        February      |        March         |            |
--------+----------------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
 Dealer | Target | Actual | %  | Target | Actual | %  | Target | Actual | %  |    TOTAL   |
--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
  P501  |   100  |    90  | 90 |   100  |    85  | 85 |   100  |    93  | 93 |    268     |
--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
  P502  |   100  |    89  | 89 |   100  |    88  | 88 |   100  |    92  | 92 |    269     |
--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+------------+
```

a) the number of months to be displayed is passed as a parameter. For quarterly report, there will be 3 months; for semi-annual there will be 6 months; for annual, all 12 months will be shown.

b) the Region, Target and Actual data are read from a database table using the SQL statement below:

```
  select concat(d.dealer_code,"-",dealer_name) as dealer
        ,s.month
        ,case 
           when s.month="1" then "January" 
          when s.month="2" then "February" 
          when s.month="3" then "March"
          when s.month="4" then "April"
          when s.month="5" then "May" 
          when s.month="6" then "June"
          when s.month="7" then "July"
          when s.month="8" then "August" 
          when s.month="9" then "September"
          when s.month="10" then "October"
          when s.month="11" then "November" 
         else "December" 
        end as month_name
       ,case
          when s.type = "PA" then "Actual"
          else "Target"
        end as type
       ,s.amount    
   from t_pbo_sales s, t_pbo_dealer d    
  where s.dealer_id = d.id
```

c) the % performance column is a computed field which is simply calculated as: actual / target * 100

d) The TOTAL column is the sum of the Actual columns only (targets are not included)

e) The cube has the following structure:
    Groups (Dimensions)
          DealerGrp - dealer
          MonthGrp - month_name, type
    Summary Fields (Measures)
         Summary field - amount

I added a Derived Measure to hold the value of the % performance column. It is appearing correctly besides the Target and Actual columns for each month but I can't figure out how to provide its value (see formula from item c above)
. 
What is the best way to accomplish this?

How do I compute the Total columns?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking how to define how many months are returned in your query?

Comment: Hi James, thanks for your reply. I just want to know how to set the value of the derived % column based on the formula Actual / Target * 100. Thanks

Comment: This question is also posted at [BIRT](http://developer.actuate.com/community/forum/index.php?/topic/34337-how-to-create-a-computed-column-based-on-other-columns-of-a-crosstab/) where it has an answer.

Comment: Yes I posted the same question in BIRT Exchange. Thanks.